# MNIST tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to extend the MNIST Tensorflow tutorial 'Deep learning for experts' where I am trying to print the final value of y_conv (from the tutorial), here is my code :

```
with sess.as_default():
    x_test=mnist.test.images[10]
    x_test=np.reshape(x_test,(-1,784))
    print(y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x:x_test,keep_prob:1}))
    print (accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: np.reshape(mnist.test.images[10],-1,784)
```

I am getting a weird value for y_conv :

> [[ 18.27762222  -3.28520679   2.48342848  -4.64049053  -6.00347185
>   -4.08683825  -1.80674195  -2.16284728  -4.48559856   1.90175676]]

although when I am printing the accuracy in the last line, I am getting a value of 1.0, which means that y_conv is matching the value of y (again from the tutorial.)
Any ideas on what could be going wrong..?

Comment: Why you say its weird?. `y_conv` doesn't seem to have `softmax` applied.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't printing y_conv with an activation function applied. If you apply a softmax function, you'll see it'll be something like:

```
[[1, 0, 0.7ish, 0, 0, 0, 0.3ish, 0.2ish, 0, 0.7ish]]
```

Try applying an activation and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks MLavrentyev, vijay m..! I am embarrassed that I missed it.. :P it worked like a charm.